# How to access value of an extra

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, extras

I want to access the extras contained in the BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND, for example if i want to access the value containd in BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_CLASS, I should use it as shown below in the code, but when I display the value of the variable "state", it was something like -245175

Are there other values contined inside BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_CLASS? how should i know them? and how should i access them?

**update**:

intent i am registered to is : `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND`

**code**:

```
switch (action) {
        case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
            Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.i("onReceive", "BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND"));

            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_CLASS, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.i("onReceive", "state: "+state));
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `getIntExtra()`, but the extra value isn't an integer. It still "works", but the content is interpreted in the wrong way, so you get a meaningless value.

The [docs for EXTRA_CLASS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#EXTRA_CLASS) say:

> Used as a Parcelable `BluetoothClass` extra field in ACTION_FOUND and ACTION_CLASS_CHANGED intents.

You should use [`getParcelableExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra%28java.lang.String%29) instead. That should give you an instance of the correct class out. Like so:

```
BluetoothClass bclass = (BluetoothClass)intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_CLASS);
```

Comment: will there be another fields inside "bclass" i can access?how can i do it. thank you

Comment: Yes. BluetoothClass is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.html